# How does google appengine measure datastore put operations

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

With the appengine pricing changes, we've been paying attention to our datastore puts. According to the pricing comparison chart we're making 2.18 million puts a day. This seems a lot higher than expected. We receive about 0.6 queries per second which means that each request is making about 60 puts!!

Using the sample code for db profiling http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/hooks.html
we measured this for a day and the most we counted was ~14,000 which seems more reasonable. Does anyone have experience with something similar on their site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The discrepancy you're seeing is because every index write is counted separately. When you do a datastore put, you're charged for the number of rows that have to be modified, so if you modified a single indexed field, you'd expect to be charged for:

- One write for the entity itself
- Two writes for the ascending index for the modified property
- Two writes for the descending index for the modified property

For a total of 5 writes. As you can see, setting properties to `indexed=False` can have a big impact on your quota usage here.

Comment: The indexes for indexed properties don't seem to be shown in the administration console. Clicking on Data -> Datastore Indexes only shows indexes explicitly defined in `index.yaml`. Is there a way to get a full list of all indexes the application uses?

Comment: @Aleksander Only composite indexes (those you define yourself) are shown there. The two built in indexes are just that, built in, and described in the docs.

Comment: So currently there are no statistics provided about their contribution towards the number of datastore operations and size occupied?

Comment: @Aleksander Not currently, no. We just announced in the release notes that we're adding stats on number of index records to the admin console, though.

Comment: @NickJohnson are there any plans to provide full, all index statistics in the production administration console?

The per entity count in development server's console can only serve as input for some approximated extrapolation regarding the actual production instance...

Comment: @AleksanderAdamowski I'm not sure what you're asking for - what sort of stats were you thinking of?